# STRING_AGG in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem with STRING_AGG in Bigquery.
I'm trying:

```
SELECT
 id,
 institution,
 COUNT(DISTINCT institution)  OVER (PARTITION BY id) as count_intitution
 STRING_AGG(DISTINCT institution,"," )  OVER (PARTITION BY id) as list_intitution
FROM
 name_table
WHERE
 DATE(created_at) = "2020-02-02"
```

and i get this error:

> Analytic function string_agg does not support DISTINCT.

BQ documentation says it allows the use of "DISTINCT"

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg

But apparently it doesn't support "partition by", why?

EDIT:

the current table is like this (it is an example, the table has more attributes)

```
|id |institution|
|1  | a         |
|1  | b         |
|2  | a         |
|2  | c         |
|3  | a         |
|1  | a         |
```

and what I want to achieve is

```
|id|count_institution|list_institution|
|1 |2                |a,b             |
|2 |2                |a,c             |
|3 |1                |a               |
```

Comment: `But apparently it doesn't support "partition by", why?` Better you ask this question to google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
  REPLACE((
      SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT i) FROM t.list_intitution i
    ) AS list_intitution
  ) 
FROM (
  SELECT
   id,
   institution,
   COUNT(DISTINCT institution)  OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS count_intitution,
   ARRAY_AGG(institution) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS list_intitution
  FROM
   name_table
  WHERE
   DATE(created_at) = "2020-02-02"
) t
```

Note: in your original query you just remove DISTINCT and use ARRAY_AGG instead of STRING_AGG, but then in outer query you process this array to form list of distinct values from that array

> Below is answer on your updated question

You can simply use GROUP BY as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT institution) AS count_institution,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT institution) AS list_institution
FROM name_table
GROUP BY id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question, as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH name_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'a' institution UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'a' 
)
SELECT id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT institution) AS count_institution,
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT institution) AS list_institution
FROM name_table
GROUP BY id
```

result is

```
Row id  count_institution   list_institution     
1   1   2                   a,b  
2   2   2                   a,c  
3   3   1                   a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily work around this:

```
SELECT id, institution,
       COUNT(DISTINCT institution)  OVER (PARTITION BY id) as list_intitution
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN institution END, ',')  OVER (PARTITION BY id) as list_intitution
FROM (SELECT t.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM name_table
      WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2020-02-02'
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on your updated question. You could simply not use `window functions`.

```
with cte1 as
(select distinct id, institution
from name_table
where date(created_at) = "2020-02-02")

select id, count(institution) count_inst, string_agg(institution,"," ) list_inst
from cte1 
group by id;
```

**Outputs**

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | count_inst | list_inst |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 |          2 | a,b       |
|  2 |          2 | a,c       |
|  3 |          1 | a         |
+----+------------+-----------+
```